# Statute of Limitations on Prosecution

Tags: california

What is the Statute of Limitations for prosecution in CA,USA on [Penal Code #308a](https://codes.findlaw.com/ca/penal-code/pen-sect-308.html)? I have tried everything. Please help?

Answer (score 1):

### 1 year

[PEN § 802](https://codes.findlaw.com/ca/penal-code/pen-sect-802.html):

> (a) Except as provided in subdivision (b), (c), (d), or (e), prosecution for an offense not punishable by death or imprisonment in the state prison or pursuant to subdivision (h) of Section 1170 shall be commenced within one year after commission of the offense.

Comment: The Question was for P.C. 308a?  Appreciate your effort to help though!

Comment: Why do you think this doesn’t apply to 308?

Comment: Didn't know it was the same exact violation?

Comment: It isn’t, this is the limitation period on all of fences (ono)

Comment: Thank you Dale M!  Not as educated as yourself.  Appreciate the help!